# Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-8

I have deployed a sample web application on Websphere8 and I am getting the following error:

Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException:

SRVE0203E: Servlet [TestServlet]: org.test.servlet.TestServlet was found, but is missing another required class. SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server. SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path.

I have checked the class path, it looks ok, but still Iam getting this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the code of the servlet? https://gist.github.com/ might of help.